PowerBI (on app.powerbi.com) do not update data from a PostgreSQL on AWS
I'm a little desperate with a problem that i can't solve.
I have a PostgreSQL in a EC2 virtual machine (with Debian) on AWS. I enable the access to this VM and database and all my developers can access remotly all this resources from their PC.
They're using DBeaver, with no problem, to connect and manipulated the PostgreSQL and Desktop PowerBI to produce Dashboards with this data. Every connection directly to the EC2 machine with our postgresql.
We can upload the Dashboards to the Azure (app.powerbi.com) and create the connection to our database, bouth operation with succesfully.
However, we can't make the update of data. It's like the query never ends or neve executes (because we don't see the querys on the pg_stat_activity).
My team tryin many things like, change the TLS, enable or desable cipher, but nothing has effect.
Someone saves ours?
edit
Error message returned by the plataform
Something went wrong
An error occurred while processing data in the dataset.
Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.
Hide details
Data source errorDataSource.Error: An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.'. Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ErrorCode = 10434. DataSourceKind = PostgreSQL. DataSourcePath = machine/database. . The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface

can you add what you have tried and error if you are facing any error?
